# Show reminder(alarm) like custom alert and perform user action on that alert in IOS

Tags: ios, swift

I want to show reminder alert to user in particular time . And perform action on that alert view . I used local notification to show reminder but it showing badge style message when app running in background . I need alternate solution for this . 
  Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1):

In AppDelegate you should write like this ( this is from my app , just only a example, use this code according to your app )

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    let completeAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    completeAction.identifier = "COMPLETE_TODO" // the unique identifier for this action
    completeAction.title = "Complete" // title for the action button
    completeAction.activationMode = .Background // UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background - don't bring app to foreground
    completeAction.authenticationRequired = false // don't require unlocking before performing action
    completeAction.destructive = true // display action in red

    let remindAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    remindAction.identifier = "REMIND"
    remindAction.title = "Remind in 30 minutes"
    remindAction.activationMode = .Background
    remindAction.destructive = false

    let todoCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory() // notification categories allow us to create groups of actions that we can associate with a notification
    todoCategory.identifier = "TODO_CATEGORY"
    todoCategory.setActions([remindAction, completeAction], forContext: .Default) // UIUserNotificationActionContext.Default (4 actions max)
    todoCategory.setActions([completeAction, remindAction], forContext: .Minimal) // UIUserNotificationActionContext.Minimal - for when space is limited (2 actions max)

    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Alert | .Badge | .Sound, categories: NSSet(array: [todoCategory]))) // we're now providing a set containing our category as an argument
    return true
  }
```

for more information go to this link :- http://jamesonquave.com/blog/local-notifications-in-ios-8-with-swift-part-2/

Comment: Thank you for your response , i used this code but when i click on "complete" action app not opening like (did receive local notification call )...

Comment: Thanks for your answer ....One question is there any another way show reminder(alarm) like custom alert and perform user action on that alert  with out local notifications.

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/local-notifications-ios8/   go through with this, hope this will help you !!